# Google PieChart in webView android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I am using this code to visualize a google piechart in a webview

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public WebView webview;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String customHtml = "<html>"
    +"<head>"
    +"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"jsapi.js\">  </script>"
    +"<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
    +"google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});"
    +"google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);"
    +"function drawChart() {"+"var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(["+"['Task', '50'],"+"['Sms',10],"+"['Contacts', 10],"+"['Music', 10],"+"['Videos TV', 10],"+"['Settings',  10]"+"]);"
    +"var options = {"
    +"      title: 'Répartition de la mémoire'"
    +"   };"
    +"  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));"
    +"  chart.draw(data, options);"
    +"}"
    +"</script>"
    +"</head>"
    +"<body>"
    +" <div id=\"piechart\" style=\"width: 400px; height: 400px;\"></div>"
    +"</body>"
    +"</html>";
       WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", customHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", null );
    return rootView;
}
```

}

I get this

[image]

Now I want to put informations on the right under the piechart

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found the following way,

```
var options = {
    title: 'Répartition de la mémoire',
    legend: { 
            position: 'bottom' 
    }
};
```

Try it, And let me know what happened.

**Update**

Sample program in html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
         ['Work',     11],
         ['Eat',      2],
         ['Commute',  2],
         ['Watch TV', 2],
         ['Sleep',    7]
       ]);

       var options = {
         title: 'My Daily Activities',
     legend: {position: 'bottom' }
       };

       var chart = new     google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

I hope this will help you. Let me know what happened.